# When piping a command to shell script, why does exiting piped command makes shell script exit?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

First of all, sorry if the title is not clear or misleading, my question is not not exactly easy to be understood out of context.

So here it is: I am running a shell script (hello.sh) that needs to relocate itself from ***/root*** to ***/***.
thus I made a simple recursion, to test from where the script is running and to make a temporary copy and launch it and **exit**(this last temporary copy will move the original file, and delete itself while still running).

```
#!/bin/sh    

IsTMP=$(echo $0 | grep "tmp")
if [ -z "$IsTMP" ]; then
        cp /root/hello.sh /tmp/hello.sh
        /bin/sh /tmp/hello.sh &
        exit
else
        unlink /hello.sh
        rsync /root/hello.sh /hello.sh
        rm /root/hello.sh
        rm /tmp/hello.sh
fi


while true; do
        sleep 5
        echo "Still Alive"
done
```

This script works totally well and suits my needs (even though it is a horrendous hack): the script is moved, and re-executed from a temporary place. However, when i pipe the shell script with a tee, just like:

```
/hello.sh | tee -a /log&
```

The behaviour is not the same:

- **hello.sh** is exiting but not **tee**
- When i try to kill tee, the temporary copy is automatically killed after a few seconds, without entering the infinite loop

This behaviour is the exact same if i replace tee with another binary (e.g. watch,...), so I am wondering if it comes from piping.

Sorry if i am not too clear about my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a suspicion that your background process hello.sh is causing tee to hang. You may want to try redirecting its output to `/dev/null`. The background process, if I'm understanding correctly, goes into the infinite while loop, thus never exiting. Being connected to its parent stdout might certainly cause tee to never exit.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you meant in that last sentence.
That is what i obseerve executing **/hello.sh | tee -a /log&**:

• First ps -> tee and first instance of hello.sh are both alive
 1762 root  0:00 {hello.sh} /bin/sh /hello.sh
 1763 root  0:00 tee -a /log

• Second ps -> First instance of hello.sh( from /root) exited, tmp instance launched, tee is still here.

   1207  1763 tee  tee -a /log
         1  1773 sh   /bin/sh /tmp/hello.sh

There is no link between tee and the second instance as ppid and pid are different. but when i kill tee, hello.sh from tmp also exits.

Answer (score 0):

> When i try to kill tee, the temporary copy is automatically killed after a few seconds, without entering the infinite loop

That's not the case. The script is *entering the infinite loop*, the *few seconds* are the five the `sleep 5` in the loop pauses, and then it is *killed* by the signal SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) because it tries to `echo "Still Alive"` to the pipe which is closed on the read end since `tee` has been killed.

> There is no link between tee and the second instance

That's not the case. There is a link, namely the pipe, the write end of which is the standard output of the parent as well as (inherited) the child shell script, and the read end is the standard input of `tee`. You can see this if you look at `ls -l /proc/pid/fd`, where *pid* is the process id of the script's shell on the one hand, and of `tee` on the other.